# Exec a command in a nginx service through docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to exec a simple command in a Nginx image service:

```
rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

The problem is when I use `command: [rm, '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf']`  my container nginx don't start.

How can I do it without use a dockerfile ? Anyone can help me ?

My service in docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
  web:
    image: nginx:1.21.1
    container_name: webdev-nginx-teste
    command: [rm, '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf']
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - net-teste
    volumes:
      - ./confs/servers/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./projects:/var/www/
      - ./confs/ssl/:/var/www/ssl
```

Comment: The `volumes:` mount will already hide everything in the image's `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory.  Running `rm confs/servers/default.conf` on the host will have the same effect.

Comment: Hide but `default.conf` still there, right ? I'd like to use port 80 for example and I can't because of `default.conf`

Comment: `Hide` means there is no longer a `default.conf` in container, you worth to hava a try.

Comment: Worked very well! I tried to use this method a while ago and didn't work, maybe I was doing something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things Docker Compose does are to run containers and create the underlying Docker-level infrastructure, like networks and named volumes.  It cannot run a host command or `exec` a command in a container.

On the other hand, given the setup you show, you don't actually need to do this.  When the `docker-compose.yml` file says

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./confs/servers/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

the contents of the host directory completely replace the original config directory from the image.  If you did run the proposed `rm` command, it would delete the `default.conf` file in the host directory; you can get the same effect by running that `rm` command directly, without involving Docker.

If you do need more involved setup you can create your own custom image `FROM nginx`.  There you could `COPY` in your configuration if it's relatively fixed, and also `COPY` in any static assets you need to serve.  You could use a pattern like an entrypoint wrapper script to do any required extra fixups at container startup time.